# If one checkbox is checked, uncheck the other and show/hide HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to do two things here.

1. I want to show/hide a piece of HTML if the yes checkbox is checked and
2. I only want the yes or the no checkbox to be checked, not both.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.test1').change(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')){
                $('#extNumber').show();
            } else {
                $('#extNumber').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<td>
    Yes<input id="yPhone" type="checkbox" class="test1">
    No<input id="nPhone" type="checkbox" class="test1">
</td>
```

Here is one question that I have--why am I not able to pass both yPhone and nPhone into a function as variables? and then check to see if the status of the checkbox is true or false?  I was thinking something like this (not working):

In this example I assigned a class to both #yPhone and #nPhone (.test1).  Then I just watch the class for a change, and anytime there is a change, I assign x and y the true/false of checked/unchecked.  However, this is not working.  Ideas?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.test1').change(function(){
                var x = document.getElementyById('#yPhone').prop("checked");
                var y = document.getElementyById('#nPhone').prop("checked");
                if((x == false) && (y == false)){
                    $('#extNumber').hide();
                } else if (x == true){
                    $('#extNumber').show();
                }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't radio buttons be the proper element to use here -- not checkboxes?

Comment: Umm...why checkboxes and not radio buttons if you only want one or the other selected but not both?

Comment: Also, since you're using jQuery, don't use `var x = document.getElementyById('#yPhone').prop("checked");`, instead use `var x = $('#yPhone').prop("checked");`

Comment: @j08691 nothing wrong with vanilla. He could also do var `x = document.getElementyById('yPhone').checked`

Comment: @RUJordan - true it will work, but there's no point in using jQuery then. Plus, the syntax is wrong (unnecessary `#` and plain JS has no prop method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix javascript & jquery unnecessarily.

Use

```
var x = $('#yPhone').prop("checked")
```

instead of

```
var x = document.getElementyById('#yPhone').prop("checked");
                           ^ Unnecessary y   ^ javascript doesn't have a prop()
```

EDIT: 1

If you want only one checkbox checked at all times, use this. ***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LgyHU/1/)***

```
$('.test1').change(function () {
    $('.test1').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    //Rest of the code
});
```

EDIT: 2

Showing a particular div when only Yes checkbox is checked.

```
$('.test1').change(function () {
    $('.test1').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    if($('#yPhone').prop('checked')) {
        $('#extNumber').show();
    } else {
        $('#extNumber').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer. This worked. @Krishna, this doesn't solve the issue of only wanting one checkbox checked at once.  Radio buttons does not solve that either.

Comment: Thanks! @Krishna Last question: how can I get the hide() to fire off when the No box is checked?  Right now, it will show() when Yes is checked, but if you check No, it does not hide().  Unchecking Yes will hide().

Answer (score 1):

you can use vanilla to find the value, the problem is you are trying to call jQuery properties in html vanilla elements... try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.test1').change(function() {

            if (this.checked){
                $('#extNumber').show();
            } else {
                $('#extNumber').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and you can put the same name and change to radio.

```
<td>
    Yes<input id="yPhone" name="phone" type="radio" class="test1">
    No<input id="nPhone" name="phone" type="radio" >
</td>
```

Comment: How does (this.checked) correlate to yPhone?  Isn't (this.checked) looking to .test1, and that is two checkboxes, not just one?

Comment: need to change the Yes and No, removing only in  `No<input id="nPhone" name="phone" type="radio" >`, the HTML is after the script in my answers

Answer (score 0):

If its a simple matter of a yes/no question then you could just use one checkbox since it only have to option = check/uncheck, true/false, yes/no...

Instaed of giving the user the choise of an yes/no answaer then ask your question like:
Do you agree? []

You can then do something like this

```
$('#agree').on('change',function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#hiddenFields').css('display','block');
    } else {
        $('#hiddenFields').css('display','none');
    }
});
```

[Heres a demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kXhd/)